# Is this an advantage of MPI_PACK over derived datatype?

Tags: mpi

Suppose a process is going to send a number of arrays of different sizes but of the same type to another process in a single communication, so that the receiver builds the same arrays in its memory. Prior to the communication the receiver doesn't know the number of arrays and their sizes. So it seems to me that though the task can be done quite easily with `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack`, it cannot be done by creating a new datatype because the receiver doesn't know enough. Can this be regarded as an advantage of MPI_PACK over derived datatypes?

There is some passage in the official document of MPI which may be referring to this:

> The pack/unpack routines are provided for compatibility with previous libraries. Also, they provide some functionality that is not otherwise available in MPI. For instance, a message can be received in several parts, where the receive operation done on a later part may depend on the content of a former part.

Comment: As pointed by Victor, the major catch is the receiver must allocate a buffer that is **known** to be "big enough" to receive the packed message. Performance wise, pack/unpack requires time to allocate and pack/unpack the data. If your program is hybrid MPI+OpenMP and you want to keep the pack/unpack approach (generally easier to write than a derived datatype), consider manually packing/unpacking the data since that can be easily parallelized with OpenMP (or even automatic parallelization if your compiler supports it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right. The way I phrase it is that with `MPI_Pack` I can make "self-documenting messages". First you store an integer that says how many elements are coming up, then you pack those elements. The receiver inspects that first int, then unpacks the elements. The only catch is that the receiver needs to know an upper bound on the number of bytes in the pack buffer, but you can do that with a separate message, or a `MPI_Probe`.

There is of course the matter that unpacking a packed message is way slower than straight copying out of a buffer.

Another advantage to packing is that it makes heterogeneous data much easier to handle. The `MPI_Type_struct` is rather a bother.

Comment: Could you please explain the point in your second paragraph a little bit more? I guess that when using a derived datatype, if the *type map* of the derived datatype on the receiver side defines a non-contiguous pattern of memory locations, first the data is received in a contiguous buffer by the MPI implementation, then copied from there to final destinations according to the type map. Am I right? If so, why do you think this is much faster than unpacking a packed message?

Comment: Getting data from an ordinary buffer is done with a straight copy loop. Very fast. With `MPI_unpack` you have to do a function call for each element. Much slower. Your point about the type map is correct and relevant, but of minor importance. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10778 for some tests that I did.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.